# Workaround issue with Kinesis Advantage, Windows 7 and the Intel USB 3.0 chipset

Tags: windows-7, usb-3, kinesis-advantage

I have a Kinesis Advantage keyboard that I love and I need to use it on a computer that has Windows 7 Enterprise edition and, apparently, the Intel USB 3.0 chipset that has a bug that causes the keyboard to lock up.

I tried workarounding it by going through the USB hub on the monitor, but it still locks up.

Any ides about a working workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by putting the USB controller in debug mode in the BIOS Setup of the machine.

Answer (score 3):

From that keyboard's [User Guide](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/advantage-userguide-9-13.pdf):

> Note: due to incomplete backwards compatibility of some USB 3.0 hardware, the
>   Advantage keyboard will not work on some USB 3.0 ports in a
>   Windows 7 environment.  This problem does not exist in Windows
>   8, Linux, or Macintosh OS X.

So your options:

- Try upgrading the Intel USB v3.0 driver to the latest version offered by Intel.
- Use a USB v2.0 (or lower) controller port.
- Use Windows 8, or another known-compatible OS.

Comment: I'm working at a bank, I cannot upgrade windows nor the driver and the USB 2 ports have the same issue.

Comment: If it's not your computer, then you'll a have to speak with your company's IT support.  That also makes your question [off-topic for SU](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), as it's about a corporate machine/network that you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the newest version (5.0.4.43) of the [Intel USB driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/65855/Intel-USB-3-0-eXtensible-Host-Controller-Driver) fixed the issue for me.